# MYSQL restore command saying I'm trying to restore to a different database?

Tags: mysql, linux

Hey guys I'm trying to restore a database called "hs" but MYSQL is saying, I'm trying to restore a database "mysql"

I've `su root` to get super user access,

```
[root@server init.d]# sudo mysql -u hs -p --database=hs < /home/hs/blankhsdb.sql
Enter password:

ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'hs'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it,

sudo mysql --database=hs < /path/to/filename.sql

maybe just a case of it getting confused as username and db are the same

Answer (score 1):

You interchange the variables there..you used 'hs' for user which is in your case, a database.

```
mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#
```

Read this example syntax here..

http://www.techiecorner.com/31/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-sql-dump-file/